# Android for each loop store value in array

Tags: android, listview, for-loop, hashtable

I am working on foreach loop in android(java).

```
    for(Hashtable<String , String> tableLang :list)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,""+tableLang.get("author"),Toast.DURATION.LONG);//this works


}
```

I am able to get the values required and print thm or toast thm. But i want to add the authors into a array. so that I can display them in a listView. plz help me

Comment: I think your toast news a call to show() for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Hashtable<String , String> tableLang :list)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,""+tableLang.get("author"),Toast.DURATION.LONG);//this works
    authors.add(tableLang.get("author"));
}
```